# Uninstall older version of application while installing latest msi

Tags: windows-installer

Is it possible to Uninstall the older version of application while just double clicking the latest installer .msi file ? 
I had a research on this and found RemovePreviousVersion and all and I got the result as 'Repair & Remove' window also. but it worked with the same version. 
What I need is it should uninstall the older version while installing the newer one.? 
 Please let me know how could I that if anyone know. 
 I'm using Visual Studio 2013, WinForms C#.,

Thanks

Comment: it depends..... how are you creating your installler?

Comment: So far I'm using VisualStudio setup project to create the installer. If its not possible with this, please what methodology should I go with ?

Answer (score 0):

Just setting RemovePreviousVersions is insufficient. This is still relevant:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/

and in addition you must increment the file versions of any binaries you need replacing.